# Splitting and Shifting Items in An Array

Tags: java

I have an array with integers in it.

What I would like to do is split the array at a position and move all items that are in front of that position to the end of the array and shift the items that are after that position to the front of the array.

Does anyone know how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
cards[cards.length - position + i] = cards[i];
```

with

```
cards[cards.length - position + i] = cut1[i];
```

Now that the error has been pointed at, it should be clear where you were going wrong.

Cheers!

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I needed. Thanks for pointing this error out to me!

Answer (score 3):

Dont re invent the wheel...

Use [List/ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)... they are there for such a logic making much more easy the operations..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        //define the maze
        String[] array = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "1", "2", "3", "4" };
        List<String> listA = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array));
        System.out.println(listA);
        // this will print [A, B, C, D, 1, 2, 3, 4]

        // then add the lower half of the cards maze
        List<String> cutList = new ArrayList<>(listA.subList(listA.size() / 2, listA.size()));
        System.out.println(cutList);
        // this will print [1, 2, 3, 4]

        // then add the upper half of the cards maze
        cutList.addAll(listA.subList(0, listA.size() / 2));
        // this will print [1, 2, 3, 4, A, B, C, D]
        System.out.println(cutList);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Simplify your code with one `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < position && position + 1 + i < cards.length; i++) {
    swapCard(cards, i, position + 1 + i);
}
```

Now, this is `swapCard` method:

```
void swapCard(Card[] cards, int x, int y) {
    Card temp = cards[x];
    cards[x] = cards[y];
    cards[y] = temp;
}
```

If `cards` is global, modify `swapCard`: `void swapCard(int x, int y)` and in `for` loop, just call `swapCard(i, position + 1 + i);`

@Erick G. Hagstrom: This is what I think:

```
position: 0  1  2  3  4
   array: 1  3  5  7  9
```

If `position = 1`, that mean `array[1] = 3` is still there and array will change to:

```
position: 0  1  2  3  4
   array: 5  3  1  7  9
```

If `position = 2`:

```
position: 0  1  2  3  4
   array: 7  9  5  1  3
```

And if position = 3:

```
position: 0  1  2  3  4
   array: 9  3  5  7  1
```

But I'm wrong. They want the array change to:

```
position: 0  1  2  3  4
   array: 5  7  9  3  1
```

where `position = 1`, and:

```
position: 0  1  2  3  4
   array: 9  7  1  3  5
```

where `position = 3`

BTW, in your example, the result of my method is: `3, 2, 1`

Comment: Try this with 3 cards 1, 2, 3 and position 1. The result should be 2, 3, 1. Your method results in 2, 1, 3. OP didn't ask for a swap, they asked for the entire array to shift.

Comment: That is my mistake! But in your example, the result of my method is: `3, 2, 1`